# Typescript mistakenly complains condition will always be true

Tags: typescript

Take following code snippet as an example:

```
class A {
    private foo : number = 3;

    public method () {
        if (this.foo === 3) {
            this.anotherMethod();

            if (this.foo === 4) {
                console.log(this.foo);
            }
        }
    }

    public anotherMethod () {
        this.foo = 4;
    }
}
```

As you see, the variable `foo` in this class is changed by the method `anotherMethod`. This make the assumption that the variable will always be "3" false. But Typescript doesn't "agree" on that. It keep showing the error:

```
error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false'
since the types '3' and '4' have no overlap.
```

How can I shut it up?

Comment: That's because `if (this.foo === 3)` deliberately *narrows* the type of `this.foo` - it's no longer `number`, it's the [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) `3`. You can explicitly widen it again if you like, `this.foo as number === 4`.

Comment: But I changed it in the method. Do I have to mandatorily cast it back to string?

Comment: It's probably better to return the new value and check that. 1. The compiler would understand you better. 2. *Other people* would be able to understand this code better. Working through side-effects is taxing when trying to understand what's happening. If I just look at `method` it's not at all clear why would `this.foo` ever change. I'll have to yo-yo through the code in order to understand if this isn't a mistake, is it intentional, and whether it's correct even then.

Comment: agree with @VLAZ here - this kind of side effects can cause more trouble. we can say that the compiler is not perfect - e.g. why can't it check what's being done in "anotherMethod", but what if the value is from an api call instead?
So the compile time check is really best effort - also I think this is the foundation of type guards so living with the limitation is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by **jonrsharpe** deserves to be expanded in a proper answer:

```
class A {

  private foo : number = 3;

  public method () {

    this.foo; // Hovering over this.foo at this point to find 
              // the inferred value, results in: (property) A.foo: number

    if (this.foo === 3) {

          this.anotherMethod();

          this.foo; // Hovering over this.foo at this point to find 
                    // the inferred value, results in: (property) A.foo: 3
                    // TypeScript narrows the type of this.foo to 3 
                    // (the numeric literal 3) instead of a number

          // You can explicitly widen it again if you like with the 
          // `as number` Type Assertion:
          if (this.foo as number === 4) {
              console.log(this.foo);
          }
      }
  }

  public anotherMethod () {
      this.foo = 4;
  }
}
```